# Limit on LUIS number of characters?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm developping a bot using MS bot framework and LUIS.

I would like the bot to answer emails of customers that are sent to our distribution list.

I have several questions:

1. When sending the bot a long email message (like is usually sent) the bot is responding with

> Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 414
>   (Request URL is too long).

Does LUIS have a limit over the number of characters? Is there a way to work around it?  If not how can I use to bot to answer emails?

2. Would it be possible to add the bot's email to a distribution list and have it reply all receipients? I tried to do that and for some reason the bot didn't reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a 500 character limit in LUIS (source: https://www.luis.ai/Help).

You could work around it by perhaps sending pieces of the email, like the subject or scrub it for most common words before sending to LUIS.

(I don't know the answer to your second question, sorry. I'd post this as a comment but my rep is too low. Are you able to run your bot in the emulator to get some sort of errors?)